# Two constructor calls inside one constructor in C#

Tags: c#, constructor, radix

I know how to call another constructor for a constructor from the same class or the base class, but how can I do both at once? Here is an example of what I am looking to achieve, noting that in a real case we might want to do something more complex than just set a property:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public BaseClass(object param)
    {
        // base constructor
    }
}

public class DerivedClass
{
    DateTime Date { get; private set; }

    public DerivedClass()
    {
        Date = GenerateDate();
    }
    public DerivedClass(object param) : base(param)
    {
        // How do I make it call DerivedClass() ?
    }
}
```

Comment: That looks like Basic Constructor Chaning: `public DerivedClass() : this(someDefaultForTheParam)` or `public DerivedClass(object param) : this()`. I am unsure in wich order to combine both a base class call and a chaining operation, but there are only two options after all.

Comment: Pretty sure you can’t have a parameterless constructor on a class derived from a class without one... You’d have to make it `BaseClass(object param = null)` or something like that.

Comment: Wrap common language with the method and call method from both constructors

Comment: _in a real case we might want to do something more complex than just set a property_ - this can be a good sign that maybe something more complex can be extracted into own method/class

Comment: @HereticMonkey:  _"you can’t have a parameterless constructor on a class derived from a class without one"_ -- not strictly true. It's difficult, because usually the parameter to the base class would be provided by the client code. But if the derived class has a reasonable way to provide the parameter to the base class, it certainly can declare a parameterless constructor.

Comment: @PeterDuniho; I was talking about the code shown in the OP, where there’s a parameterless constructor without reference to the base class’s constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code actually compiles in Sharp Lab. Not that I had to fix a few secondary things.

```
using System;

public class BaseClass
{
    public BaseClass(object param)
    {
        // base constructor
    }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public DateTime Date { get; private set; }

    public DerivedClass() : this(new object()) { }

    public DerivedClass(object param) : base(param)
    {
        //Do Date = GenerateDate(); here
        //Had to cut your pseudo code, as it broke compilation
    }
}
```

You had it the wrong way around: You need `DerivedClass()` to call `DerivedClass(object param)`. With multiple Constructors, the one you actually code out is always the one with the *most* arguments. All other Constructors are just there to chain towards it, giving a default value each step.

Comment: While this didn't solve my problem, it made my realise that I wasn't asking the right question. For the case I presented, this does solve the issue, with the only exception that I would use `null` instead of `new object()`. Marking as accepted answer.

Comment: @DCD I had to guess a default value, and was torn between any instance or null. But in the end, the default can be whatever you want it to be.